# Mathcad, решение задачи методом Гаусса

Tags: математика, матрицы

[image: вот сама задача]

Подскажите, какие должны быть аргументы `submatrix`, чтобы получить последний столбец матрицы (решение системы), не могу нигде найти информацию по этому поводу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`submatrix(Ag,0,3,4,4)` методом подбора)